# else if doesn't work in ajax login form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I made the code below by looking at google and combining proccess.php, submit form and ajax, but I do not know where my mistake is. The code does not seem to work.

**proccess.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

  //check login status and etc

      if ($data['status'] == 'ok' && $data['loggedinuser']['username'] == "$username") {  
          echo 'ok';
      } elseif ($data['message'] == 'checkpoint' && $data['status'] == 'fail') {
          echo 'checkpoint';
      } elseif ($data['errortype'] == 'invaliduser' && $data['status'] == 'fail') {
          echo 'wrongusername';
      } elseif ($data['errortype'] == 'badpassword' && $data['status'] == 'fail') {
          echo 'wrongpassword';
      } elseif ($data['errortype'] == 'unusablepassword' && $data['status'] == 'fail') {
          echo 'unusablepassword';
} else {
          echo '';
}
?>
```

**index.php**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#loginform").submit(function() {
    if ($('#username').val().length > 3 || $('#password').val.length > 3) {
      var pdata = $(this).serialize();
      $.ajax({
        url: "proccess.php",
        data: pdata,
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function() {
          $("#pesan").html("<h4>Loading...</h4>");
        },
        success: function(pesan) {
          console.log(pesan);
          if (console.log(pesan) == "ok")
            $("#pesan").html("<h4>Login Success...<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1'; url=redirect.php'></h4>");
          else if (console.log(pesan) == "gagal")
            $("#pesan").html("<h4>Error!</h4>");
          else if (console.log(pesan) == "wrongusername")
            $("#pesan").html("<h4>Wrong Username!</h4>");
          else if (console.log(pesan) == "wrongpassword")
            $("#pesan").html("<h4>Wrong Password!</h4>");
          else if (console.log(pesan) == "checkpoint")
            $("#pesan").html("<h4>need checkpoint</h4>");
          else if (console.log(pesan) == "accountblocked")
            $("#pesan").html("<h4>your account blocked.</h4>");
          else
            $("#pesan").html("<h4>Invalid username and/or password.</h4>");
        }

      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="pesan" class="text-align-center">
  <h4>Login to your account</h4>
</header>
<form class="no-margin" method="POST" id="loginform">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
        <input name="username" id="username" type="username" class="form-control input-lg input-transparent" placeholder="Username" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
        <input name="password" id="password" type="password" class="form-control input-lg input-transparent" placeholder="Password" required>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="">
    <button id="masuk" type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-danger">
      <span class="small-circle"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></span>
      <small>Sign In</small>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: What does not work?

Comment: Echo/var_dump your variables before you run your checks, then you can see if it's supposed to be matching one of your elses.

Comment: @aynber i have echo the variables in proccess.php, and the output is same with the echo above...

Comment: @RikardOlsson No error, i have check it with ini_set adn error_reporting

Comment: @some when i click login, the page just refresh/reload :(

Comment: Add `e.preventDefault();` at the top of your submit function.

Comment: remove those console.log first.. `console.log(pesan)== "ok"`

Comment: @aynber now its say Invalid username and/or password.

Comment: Since it looks like you want to compare the output of PHP to determine what the HTML should be, all the statements that look like this: `if (console.log(pesan)== "ok") ` should be changed to `if (pesan== "ok") `

Comment: @SebastianKrysiak its still makes no different

Comment: What does your console say, when you echo out pesan?

Comment: @mieburungdara next thing You want to do is replacing Your $data with $_POST, or just type a `$data = $_POST;` at the begining of proccess.php

Comment: @everyone when i add    e.preventDefault(); and change    if (console.log(pesan)== "ok")  to     if (pesan== "ok")  it works, but not redirect the page, just reload

Comment: @DhruvSaxena i changed and its makes work but still cant reload

Comment: @aynber the pesan is response from proccess.php and i dont know how to echo pesan in html :(

Comment: You're already logging the response in the browser console. Take a look at that. Everywhere that you're using `console.log(pesan)==`, change it to just `pesan==`. Console.log is for writing to the console, it is not used for validation.

Comment: @aynber its say Undefined index: errortype and Undefined index: mesage in proccess.php

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Answer (score 1):

**Fix required in PHP:**

Please receive the data sent by Javascript:

```
$data = $_REQUEST['data'];
```

**Fixes required in Javascript:** 
Changing your `if` statements as follows:

```
if (pesan == "ok"){
    $("#pesan").html("<h4>Login Success...");
    window.location = "redirect.php";
}
else if (pesan == "gagal") 
    $("#pesan").html("<h4>Error!</h4>");
else if (pesan == "wrongusername") 
    $("#pesan").html("<h4>Wrong Username!</h4>");
else if (pesan == "wrongpassword") 
    $("#pesan").html("<h4>Wrong Password!</h4>");
else if (pesan == "checkpoint") 
    $("#pesan").html("<h4>need checkpoint</h4>");
else if (pesan == "accountblocked") 
    $("#pesan").html("<h4>your account blocked.</h4>"); 
else 
    $("#pesan").html("<h4>Invalid username and/or password.</h4>");
```

Please notice how redirection is done using Javascript:

```
window.location = "redirect.php";
```

Comment: i change it now, but still makes no different :(

Comment: The AJAX code is only going to send `username` and `password` that will be received in `$data`. Now, is there actually some code in place where the snippet above only includes a comment: `//check login status and etc`? If yes, then it's not necessary to cram everything in `$data` - use other variables to hold `status`, `message`, etc and use those in all your `elseif ` conditions. If there is no code right now, then the code provided here is still incomplete and there's plenty of work that needs to be done to validate and verify user credentials.

Comment: my proccess.php just need username and password then proccessing it...
$data['status'] is array from json_decode

Comment: Since that code is not shown here, people here won't be able to tell how it affects or partakes in the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if key exists in the $data array before running it inside if else. You have to use isset() to check if the array element exists.

Try to rephrase your code as in the following:

```
if($data['status']=="ok" && $data['loggedinuser']['username'] == "$username")
{
    echo "ok";
}
else
{
    if( isset($data['message']) ) {
      echo $data['message'];
    } 
    elseif( isset($data['errortype']) ) {
      echo $data['errortype'];
    }   
}
```

Note you can echo $data["message"] and $data["error"] directly unlike they you did it.